# Java run timeout

Tags: java

I am working on a USACO 2016 Bronze Feb Problem 3, Here is my code and it works for the first 6 testing cases. But from Case 7-10, it shows timeout. I can't figure out how to fix the problem. Please do help!

[usaco problem](http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=617)

**Here is the problem:**

Farmer John's N cows are each standing at distinct locations (x1,y1)…(xn,yn) on his two-dimensional farm (1≤N≤100, and the xi's and yi's are positive odd integers of size at most B). FJ wants to partition his field by building a long (effectively infinite-length) north-south fence with equation x=a (a will be an even integer, thus ensuring that he does not build the fence through the position of any cow). He also wants to build a long (effectively infinite-length) east-west fence with equation y=b, where b is an even integer. These two fences cross at the point (a,b), and together they partition his field into four regions.

FJ wants to choose a and b so that the cows appearing in the four resulting regions are reasonably "balanced", with no region containing too many cows. Letting M be the maximum number of cows appearing in one of the four regions, FJ wants to make M as small as possible. Please help him determine this smallest possible value for M.

For the first five test cases, B is guaranteed to be at most 100. In all test cases, B is guaranteed to be at most 1,000,000.

**INPUT FORMAT (file balancing.in):**

The first line of the input contains two integers, N and B. The next n lines each contain the location of a single cow, specifying its x and y coordinates.
OUTPUT FORMAT (file balancing.out):
You should output the smallest possible value of M that FJ can achieve by positioning his fences optimally.

```
SAMPLE INPUT:

7 10
7 3
5 5
9 7
3 1
7 7
5 3
9 1
SAMPLE OUTPUT:
2
```

Here is my code:

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;
    
    public class ACO2016FebP3{

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
     Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("balancing.in"));
     PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File("balancing.out"));
     
     int N = in.nextInt();
     int B = in.nextInt();
     
     Point[] loc = new Point[N];
     int minX=B, minY=B;
     for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
         int x = in.nextInt();
         int y = in.nextInt();
         loc[i] = new Point(x, y);
         if(x < minX){ minX = x;}
         if(y < minY){ minY = y;}
     }
     
     int result = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
     for(int a = minX+1; a < B-2; a+=2){
         for(int b = minY+1; b < B-2 ; b += 2){
            int[] mArr = new int[4];
            for(Point p : loc){
               if(p.x<a && p.y<b){
                  mArr[0]++;
               }
               if(p.x>a && p.y<b){
                  mArr[1]++;
               }
               if(p.x>a && p.y>b){
                  mArr[2]++;
               }
               if(p.x<a && p.y>b){
                  mArr[3]++;
               }
            }
            int mMax = findMax(mArr);
            result = Math.min(result, mMax);
         }
     }
     out.println(result);
     out.close();
   }
   
   public static int findMax(int[] arr){
      int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
      for(int e : arr){
         if(e > max){
            max = e;
         }
      }
      return max;
   }
   
}

class Point{
   int x, y;
   Point(int xx, int yy){
      x = xx;
      y = yy;
   }
}
```

Here is testing input data which costs a timeout error

```
100 5000
4897 217
3507 4953
633 4669
4375 491
4185 1599
1593 3363
931 4501
4823 1585
3621 3631
4077 1373
489 3847
547 4713
4893 773
1011 4881
1965 541
3455 3985
107 4957
37 4977
4927 4961
1453 1335
3133 1267
83 4743
4603 1439
887 4519
2483 741
1429 1169
461 839
255 3801
1261 3951
933 4465
1521 2245
1197 4809
2451 1017
4053 435
4043 1167
3345 433
1079 2539
621 3375
4047 1185
535 2219
417 3387
571 673
3945 1355
849 3473
3775 797
97 4203
4133 1367
4305 1553
4199 521
333 5
485 2633
937 4879
919 1561
3667 567
1527 4463
4659 4387
785 4753
1529 393
401 4623
1043 1433
317 3369
4833 1367
4493 173
2789 957
573 4001
257 1439
3721 983
925 3141
3753 3631
2393 401
649 1681
3669 11
1241 4571
891 2465
3775 1033
4369 3631
1921 209
4553 1529
321 4835
2637 53
837 499
2317 721
3413 1661
1295 4991
687 3729
161 4757
811 4871
471 3189
883 389
4009 635
781 143
1165 2541
2111 69
3425 187
763 2159
3523 1107
1659 4965
1089 1355
3559 1255
133 15
```

Comment: hi, could you print the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: My first idea would be this: do not create a new mArr during every loop iteration - create it once, fill it with zeroes in every iteration - saves the overhead of memory allocation. - Generally, your code likely is just too slow and inefficient for large data sets.

Comment: how much time do you have to solve given test case?

Comment: Each question might take about 30-60 minutes in Bronze Level

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. Instead of bruce force, I just check the all possible x and y as for a and b.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ACO2016FebP3{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
     Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("balancing.in"));
     PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File("balancing.out"));
     
     int N = in.nextInt();
     int B = in.nextInt();
     
     Point[] loc = new Point[N];
     for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
         int x = in.nextInt();
         int y = in.nextInt();
         loc[i] = new Point(x, y);
     }
     
     int result = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

     for(int xIdx = 0; xIdx<N; xIdx++){
         for(int yIdx = 0; yIdx<N; yIdx++){
            int a = loc[xIdx].x-1;
            int b = loc[yIdx].y-1;
            int[] mArr = new int[4];
            for(Point p : loc){
               if(p.x<a && p.y<b){
                  mArr[0]++;
               }
               if(p.x>a && p.y<b){
                  mArr[1]++;
               }
               if(p.x>a && p.y>b){
                  mArr[2]++;
               }
               if(p.x<a && p.y>b){
                  mArr[3]++;
               }
            }
            int mMax = findMax(mArr);
            result = Math.min(result, mMax);
         }
     }
     /*
     int result = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
     for(int a = minX+1; a < B-2; a+=2){
         for(int b = minY+1; b < B-2 ; b += 2){
            int[] mArr = new int[4];
            for(Point p : loc){
               if(p.x<a && p.y<b){
                  mArr[0]++;
               }
               if(p.x>a && p.y<b){
                  mArr[1]++;
               }
               if(p.x>a && p.y>b){
                  mArr[2]++;
               }
               if(p.x<a && p.y>b){
                  mArr[3]++;
               }
            }
            int mMax = findMax(mArr);
            result = Math.min(result, mMax);
         }
     }
     */
     out.println(result);
     out.close();
   }
   
   public static int findMax(int[] arr){
      int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
      for(int e : arr){
         if(e > max){
            max = e;
         }
      }
      return max;
   }
   
}

class Point{
   int x, y;
   Point(int xx, int yy){
      x = xx;
      y = yy;
   }
}
```